# A logical affix riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix stands tall amongst seas and oceans
> My infix can be used to describe itself, or some time
> My suffix can be blown, bent, or even broken
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A logical solution is

> mastermind

My prefix stands tall amongst seas and oceans

> mast - sailing ships masts are tall posts

My infix can be used to describe itself, or some time

> term - this term can describe a duration

My suffix can be blown, bent, or even broken

> mind - can be blown by something astounding or broken by a mind-bending puzzle

Comment: Gur "ybtvpny" nfcrpg ersreerq gb gur obneq tnzr [Znfgrezvaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game))